# Why I can't using arrayformula in lookup function with autofill from google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, right now I'm building a KPI that need to create a single flow KPI submission using Google Form to Google Sheet. You can see my example in sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X8NHK6PV6107qkSw3Vuol-OsZ0zVt2p34zTQqRI7DpQ/edit#gid=730791776) and Google form [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1tpzOtvyrFvxVEuhaTcJcgFUwGR7qLlAO2AtBS44Rl-g/edit?usp=sharing)

[First Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJYkW.png)

[Second Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecWzl.png)

Right now I'm using lookup value from 3 criteria (with INDEX and MATCH function) that i made but here's the problem. I know that google form will create a new row under the existing row instead of replicate it when a submission was entered. But, i need to fill my 'E' and 'F' column (from my [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X8NHK6PV6107qkSw3Vuol-OsZ0zVt2p34zTQqRI7DpQ/edit#gid=730791776)) automatically, after the google form or 'A until D' column was entered.

I've tried some code using Script editor in Sheet that will generate one active column that i highlighted to drag down automatically when im running the script. This method won't be effective if i had to apply it one by one for 10-20 columns...

Here's the google script code:

```
function myFormula(){
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var tabs = ['Form Responses 1'];
  var columns = [5,6];
  if(tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1){
    var cell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
    var col = cell.getColumn();
    if(columns.indexOf(col) !== -1){
      if(cell.getFormula() !== ""){
        var destination = activeSheet.getRange(2,col,activeSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1); 
        cell.copyTo(destination);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, can you guys please help me with it? I will appreciate it if you would help me with my projects. Thankyou.

Comment: If you want help with your Apps Script please give permissions for the example sheet, at the moment it is not available to access.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation @iansedano , however this problem has been solved by JPV. And i prefer to use google sheet equation. Once again, thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered this formula in G2

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), vlookup(to_text(B2:B)&C2:C&D2:D, {to_text('Database for Each Indicator'!A:A)&'Database for Each Indicator'!B:B&'Database for Each Indicator'!C:C, 'Database for Each Indicator'!D:E}, {2, 3}, 0),))
```

The output of this formula should expand when new forms are submitted.
See if that works for you?